# Opening a edmx file gets error "Object reference not set to instance of an object"

Tags: entity-framework-6

I get "Object reference not set to instance of an object" when I try to open my edmx file in EF 6. Is there any way to figure out what its missing?

Answer (score 0):

Closing and opening the visual studio worked for me.

Comment: Your reply is good for an comment, but not as an answer. It is rather advise then an solution

Comment: Re-opening visual studio did not work for me

Comment: did not work for me either

Answer (score 0):

Same as [Cannot import anymore tables into edmx. "Running transformation: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76388322/cannot-import-anymore-tables-into-edmx-running-transformation-system-nullrefe/76424120#76424120)

Go to

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\Templates\Includes
```

Start Notepad **in administrator mode**, and open the file (substituting Community for Professional or Enterprise depending on your version):

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\Templates\Includes\EF6.Utility.CS.ttinclude
```

Update the following code in DynamicTextTransformation (approx line 1920) and change:

```
_generationEnvironment = type.GetProperty("GenerationEnvironment", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

to

```
_generationEnvironment = type.GetProperty("GenerationEnvironment", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
```

Basically, you need to add the `BindingFlags.Public` to the options inside the `GenerationEnvironment`.

This is a documented bug from VS2022. It looks like it will be fixed in new releases. (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Cannot-import-anymore-tables-into-edmx/10368835)