# Cannot import anymore tables into edmx. "Running transformation: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2022, edmx

Cannot import anymore tables into edmx. "Running transformation: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Fixed in future versions of VS: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Cannot-import-anymore-tables-into-edmx/10368835

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Go to

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\Templates\Includes
```

Start Notepad in administrator mode, and open the file (substituting Community for Professional or Enterprise depending on your version):

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\Templates\Includes\EF6.Utility.CS.ttinclude
```

Update the following code in DynamicTextTransformation (approx line 1920) and change:

```
_generationEnvironment = type.GetProperty("GenerationEnvironment", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

to

```
_generationEnvironment = type.GetProperty("GenerationEnvironment", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
```

Comment: This worked, what is it doing?